# Ejabberd server is not showing admin panel

Tags: ios, xmpp, ejabberd

I am developing an iOS chat app by using XMPP. I have successfully installed ejabbered on my MAC with the help of below Tutorial :

"http://shubhank101.github.io/iOSAndroidChaosOverFlow/2016/08/Chat-Application-Using-XMPP-Swift-Tutorial".

But I am unable to access admin panel. 
Whenever I am trying to hit "http://localhost.com:5280/admin/" found an error "failed to open page" and also it takes lot of time to open. I researched a lot but could not find solution.

Comment: Have you started Ejabbered services ?

Comment: yes. i runned command of ejabbered live and start also

Comment: What was the response from terminal when you executed command for start?

Comment: when i run the start command nothing happens jumps to next line simply

Comment: You executed this command : sbin/ejabberdctl live ?

Comment: yes. after this ejabbered goes live.

Comment: but if i run start then simply move to next line

Comment: Now are you able to open admin panel ?

Comment: no i am not. i have tried everything but dnt knw why unable to open

Comment: I think there is something wrong with your installation. You should reinstall.

Comment: I reinstalled three times but failed.. when i am installing cluster is set to No. cluster affects? admin panel?

Comment: Nope cluster doesn’t affect your admin panel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to access http://localhost.com 
It should be either http://localhost:5280/admin or http://127.0.0.1/admin